# How to parse large XML file with Java, chunk by chunk

Tags: java, sax, stax

I'm trying to parse a large XML file with Java, a chunk at a time, so that the server doesn't have to store the whole file in memory.

My Javascript code slices the file using the File API slice function and sends about 2mb at a time to the server. I'm using AppEngine, so I can't save to disc.

For example, chunk one:

```
<message:DataSet>
   <series>...</series>
   <series>...</series>
   <series>...</series> (and so on, thousands)
```

Chunk two, three etc until eof:

```
   <series>...</series>
   <series>...</series>
   <series>...</series> (more)
```

Is there a parser of some type where a context/state/cursor could be saved so that parsing could be resumed with the additional chunks of data?

Or, otherwise, is there a solution that can parse large XML files without loading the whole file into memory?

```
parser = new Parser(previousState);
parser.parse(moreData);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. Explain what the problem is, what the result is you get and what the result is you want instead.

Comment: I want a parser that can be reinitialized from a saved state and resume parsing the next chunk. That code was simply to demonstrate my current solution

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achive and how StAX or SAX are unsuitable to your problem. What exactly do you mean by "reinitialized from saved state"? What state? With StAX or SAX you usually manage state on your own. You only have to ensure that the XML is well-formed.

Comment: By state I mean, if the parser had processed just part of the file - the current location, current event etc could be saved so that the parser can be recreated later and ready to resume parsing where it left off.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Java's XML parser implementations. Maybe you should write the content to a temporary file and parse it after the transmission is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding a solution, Aalto, which is an extension on StAX that stores a state "required to keep track of parsing state, location, at byte-accurate offsets"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with similar requirements, I came across the Aalto XML processor, which is almost exactly what I was after. It features so-called non-blocking (asynchronous) XML parsing. It adds a special event to StAX, EVENT_INCOMPLETE, which allows more input to be fed-in later.

For example:

```
<root>value</root>
```

```
AsyncXMLInputFactory inputF = new InputFactoryImpl();

//Parse part 1
byte[] input_part1 = "<root>val".getBytes("UTF-8");
AsyncXMLStreamReader<AsyncByteArrayFeeder> parser = inputF.createAsyncFor(input_part1);

//Process events here

//Parse part 2
byte[] input_part2 = "ue</root>".getBytes("UTF-8");
parser.getInputFeeder().feedInput(input_part2);

//Process more events here
```

Larger example [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml/wiki/Code-sample:-Async-parsing)

Aalto XML project page on GitHub [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml/)

**Update:**
There is also, [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox), which has even more features, including P_INPUT_PARSING_MODE, which allows for more lenient parsing (eg multiple root elements). Both solutions are from FasterXML.